# OpenCSV Classnames are not Resolving

Tags: java, javafx, opencsv

I'm trying to use OpenCSV in a JavaFX project. But can't get the classnames to resolve. I've tried other solutions through StackOverflow with no success.
Of course I've cleaned and rebuilt.
I've tried deleting my .m2 folder, then in terminal using mvn clean install.

Below you can see I have the OpenCSV in my external Libraries (installed through pom.xml).
And I have it as dependency in Project Settings > Project > Dependencies

I have no clue why it's not resolving.

[image]
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.epls</groupId>
    <artifactId>DeliverySupplies</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>DeliverySupplies</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.9.2</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dlsc.formsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>formsfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>11.6.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-javafx</artifactId>
            <version>12.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.epls.deliverysupplies.DeliveryApp
                            </mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

module-info.java

```
module com.example.delivorysupplies {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    requires org.controlsfx.controls;
    requires com.dlsc.formsfx;
    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx;

    opens com.epls.deliverysupplies to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.epls.deliverysupplies;
}
```

Comment: Maybe post the output from the command line of `mvn compile` . You can do `mvn compile >postme.txt 2>&1` and copy and paste that file

Comment: Where is your `module-info` file?

Comment: SedJ601, That was it! I was missing OpenCSV in my module-info file. I'll update my question with the module-file (missing OpenCSV) and if you want to then provide an answer pointing out the correction, I'll be happy to mark it as the solution.

Comment: @JonR85, write an answer and accept it.

Comment: I normally do that. I just wanted to give credit (and internet points) where credit was due.